# Proof that winding number is integer - what does lifting mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, winding-number

> **Problem:** Let $\alpha:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ be a closed curve $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=1$. Then exists a *unique* $\tilde{\alpha}: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\tilde{\alpha}(0)=0$ and $\exp \circ \tilde{\alpha} = \alpha$.

I am having trouble understanding the proof(italics part) - what *exactly* is meant?

> **Proof:** For any point $a \in \mathbb{C}^*$ exists an open neighborhood $V$, such that $\exp^{-1}(V) = \bigsqcup_n U_n$, where each $U_n$ is homeomoprhically mapped onto $V$.
>
> By Heine Borel, we deduce exictence of division $[0,1]$ such that $\alpha([a_n,a_{n+1}])$ is contained in an open set $V$ as above.
>
> (NOT understand) *We can then lift the whole curve, by inductively lifting pieces in the corresponding parallel horizontal strips such that they glue at initial and end points.*

Comment: This is one thing in (Algebraic or not) Topology (related also to homotopy and stuff) that I am completely unable to even begin thinking in how to explain it without a blackboard and some chalk...sorry. Mi advice is: grab some good textbook in AT and read there about "lifting": in Munkres' "Topology", for example, or Kosniowski's "A First Course in Algebraic Tolopogy"

Comment: This was from Freitag's Complex Analysis p243... I believe Frietag does not expect us to have these topological prerequisites?

Comment: That, imo, is an excellent pair of books in complex analysis and, as it is usually required, some basic topology is assumed. Now, lifting problems and stuff wouldn't qualify in **my** book as "basic knowledge of topology", but I think that anyone messing with this stuff should be able to read a little about this in some book and understand the basic ideas.

Comment: All this to say that choosing the correct branch, $\log z $ is analytic and continuous on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,\infty)$ and $\log(1) = 0$. Let $\tilde{\alpha}(t) = \log (\alpha(t))$.

Comment: Also $\tilde{\alpha}$ is unique only if we ask it to be continuous (since $\exp(z+2i\pi k ) =\exp$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have the subdivision of $[0,1]$ such that $\alpha([a_n,a_{n+1}])$ is contained in an open $V$ and we have a lift $\tilde{\alpha}_n:[a_n,a_{n+1}] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ such that the composition $\exp \circ \tilde{\alpha}_n([a_n,a_{n+1}]) = \alpha([a_n,a_{n+1}])$. Let us start with the partition $[0,a_1]$, then we have an open set, call it $V_0$, where $\alpha([0,a_1])$ has a lift and a collection $\bigsqcup_n U_n^0$ with each $U_n^0 \approx V_0$. Select one of these $U_n^0$ and call it $O_0$. Now, for the partition $[a_1,a_2]$, we have the open set $\alpha([a_1,a_2]) \subset V_1$ and collection $\bigsqcup_n U_n^1$. Notice each $U_n^1$ contains one of $\exp^-1(\alpha(a_1))$ and we choose $O_1=U_n^1$ such that $U_n^1 \cap O_0 \neq \emptyset$. Thus $\alpha([0,a_2])$ has a lift $\tilde{\alpha}:[0,a_2]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $$ \tilde{\alpha}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}\tilde{\alpha}_0(x) & x \in [0,a_1] \\ \tilde{\alpha}_1(x) & x \in [a_1,a_2]\end{array}\right.$$

Repeat this process by induction to cover $[0,1]$ and we arrive at the lift $\tilde{\alpha}$ of $\alpha$. At the risk of repeating *ad nauseam*, that is $\tilde{\alpha}$ is such that $\exp \circ \tilde{\alpha} = \alpha$.